# how to do the test on forms PHUNIT + Selenium + code igniter

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, integration-testing

I started to design software test and use `selenium` with `phpunit`, then I've the following situation

1. I need to development the test for `code igniter`
2. We need the setup the session with data on code igniter
3. I've a 2 forms the first capture the data fields and I use it to generate the second
4. I use the following function to capture the input in the first a generete the second form

```php
class HistorialPeajesFecha  extends  ConsultasWebController
{
   ...
   public function seleccioneFecha()
   {
      $this->idVehiculo =  $this->input->post('placa');
      // I need to generate info with the system session with codeigniter 
      //how I do the setup the session to do the test
      $this->session = $this->session->userdata('myproject');
      $idUsuario = $this->session['id_usuario'];
      $results = $this->factura->listarHistorialPagos( $idVehiculo, $idUsuario  );
      $data = array(
        'idVehiculo' => $this->idVehiculo,
        'attributesForm' => array('id' => 'form_seleccion_fecha'),
        'other' => $results
      );
      $this->load->view( 'consultasWeb/templateHeaderView');
      $this->load->view( 'consultasWeb/templateMenuView', $data );
      $this->load->view( 'consultasWeb/historialFecha/seleccioneFechaView', $data );
   }
   ...
}
```

My question is, how I design the test to check the output view ('consultasWeb/historialFecha/seleccioneFechaView') with the input with the first form?.

**URL 1 FORM** :  localhost/myproject/index.php/consultasWeb/historialFecha/

**URL 2 FROM** :  localhost/myproject/index.php/consultasWeb/historialFecha/seleccioneFechaView

Answer (score 1):

For phpunit in codeyou can download composer and install 
http://kenjis.github.io/ci-phpunit-test/